# SSAS Dimension Processing Duplicate Key Error Without Hierarcy

Tags: ssas

I've just created an item dimension in ssas, have not added any hierarchies, have confirmed there are no null values in my table, have confirmed there are no duplicate keys in my table, yet I still get the duplicate key error. I have the primary key set on the item key field. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dim_Items](
[item_key] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[item_no] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[item_pref] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[item_div] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[item_cus] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[item_desc_1] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[item_desc_2] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[cus_part_no] [varchar](75) NOT NULL,
[item_loc] [char](3) NOT NULL,
[stk_uom] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[pur_uom] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[pur_to_stk_ratio] [decimal](11, 6) NOT NULL,
[mat_cost_type] [char](3) NOT NULL,
[mat_cost_desc] [char](15) NOT NULL,
[inv_category] [varchar](13) NOT NULL,
[stocked] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[controlled] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[pur_or_mfg] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[comm_cd] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[comm_desc] [char](30) NOT NULL,
[byr_plnr_cd] [int] NOT NULL,
[byr_plnr_name] [char](64) NOT NULL,
[min_ord_qty] [decimal](13, 4) NOT NULL,
[item_saftey_stk] [decimal](13, 4) NOT NULL,
[mrp_ord_up_to] [decimal](13, 4) NOT NULL,
[lead_time] [decimal](4, 1) NOT NULL,
[last_MPN] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[last_mfg] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[aml_list] [varchar](1100) NOT NULL,
[where_used] [varchar](6000) NOT NULL,
```

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL9yJ.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbe4v.png)

Comment: How many rows do you get from this?:  `SELECT * FROM Dim_Items WHERE item_pref='{type in that value from the error message}'`

Comment: 1 row, all of the item_pref values are unique as well.

Comment: When I rerun the process dimension it will sometimes give the error for different columns like item_no or item_desc_1.

Comment: Verify that your cube is pointing to the database & server that you think it is.

Comment: I verified the server and database in the data source and actually checked the table with the explore data option. I also refreshed the data source view. No luck.

Comment: I removed the item_no, item_desc_1, item_pref, last_mfg, and where_used columns from the dimension and it will process. Not a solution but thought that may be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelSchillaci what's the collation of your SQL database? Case sensitive? Can you try Tab's query again but do WHERE lcase(item_pref)=lcase(<value from screenshot>)?

Comment: The collation is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS". When running the query you suggested I'm still getting only one row.

Comment: Ok, so for the columns referenced above I changed the item key trimming from "Right" to "None" and it fixed my problem for all of the columns except for item_desc_1. Item_desc_1 was throwing an duplicate key error on the value 'N/A', which is my default NULL replacement and is used in many of the other columns. I changed the NULL replacement to '' (blank) instead and now it runs. Although I can't explain any of this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by a TAB at the end of the field value. When I changed the dimension attribute key trimming property from "RIGHT" to "NONE" it fixed the issue. The better solution would be to remove tabs from the original data source using something like:

```
    replace(item_no,char(9),'')
```

I was able to identify the issue when I noticed running the following query returned 2 rows instead of 1 when not using a wildcard:

```
    SELECT * FROM Dim_Items WHERE item_pref like'{value from the error message}'+'%'
```